# Vim: Is it possible to bind a key to open search (i.e. put me in the command mode having entered a slash, but do not type anything)

Tags: vim

While vim's way of doing things is generally good, I feel like there are aspects that really get in the way as somebody who is not completely committed to vim for text-editing.

This means that I am hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and typing slashes into files in Sublime Text, and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in vim, scrolling down a page.

Similar things happen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and `:w` and custom mapping `;` to `:` still doesn't make it as convenient and fail-safe as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Not to mention in PuTTY, Ctrl+S does something rather upsetting (it suspends output from the terminal till Ctrl+Q is pressed). Basically, IMHO some things (like switching to a "find mode" and saving the file) are good to attach to a global left-hand home-row shortcut chord rather than requiring the user to mess about in a modal command line. It simply is too often used to subject the user to these mode changes. I suppose this isnt a legitimate complaint because the entirety of vim is constructed around the modal concept, and these functionalities are a result of that.

In any case I'd like to make it a bit easier on my brain because I've tried for a while now to keep it all intact and it's simply too much (I have more or less internalized the switching between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on a windows machine on a desktop keyboard and the use of the thumb for the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on my Macbook, but this modal text editor business seems to be too much). It did not take too much deliberation for me to decide that global homerow key chords are simply more intuitive.

Mapping Ctrl+S to `:w` is trivial, so the question here is about the find mode. I want to bind Ctrl+F to put me in find mode, but repeating it should not type slashes into the find command. Can this be done? Is there perhaps a colon-command that when executed simply drops me into the current find-command-buffer-thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.vimrc` add:

```
inoremap <C-f> <Esc>/
noremap <C-f> <Esc>/
```

In whatever mode you are in, this will put you in "find" mode (it actually just types a slash in the command line which you can use to search).  With these bindings it will work for all modes, even if you are in insert mode.

Comment: Oh yeah i think the combination of Esc and / will drop me back into an empty find prompt so that will actually work! I should have just mesed around a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

do you want this?

```
nnoremap <c-f> /
```

if you like you can also try

```
nnoremap <c-f> q/
```

the 2nd mapping brings you to a search history window. you could choose previous search keywords/patterns. also available to type new pattern (by pressing `i`)

btw, there is no `find` mode

Answer (score 1):

Mappings can be defined separately for the different modes in Vim, see `:help map-modes`. This automatically takes care of your proposed `<C-f>` mapping: Initially, you're in *normal mode*, then the search pattern is entered in *command-line mode*.

If you so far only occasionally use Vim, and find it too "different", several things may make the switch easier:

- *easy Vim* (`evim` or `vim -y`) defaults to insert mode
- on Windows, `:behave mswin` and the `$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` script create some common Windows shortcuts
- graphical GVIM has menu items like *Edit > Find...* and toolbars.

Some things like the flow-control freeze on `<C-s>` in terminals are unfortunate, mostly historical accidents; you can't blame Vim for those.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to map anything. `/` is expressive enough and is definitely not slower than `<C-f>`. Same for `<C-s>` which, despite a certain familiarity, is not much better than `:w<CR>`. You are learning a new tool, remember?

What you should focus your efforts on is getting confortable with Vim's modality. The simple fact that, for you, doing a search involves hitting `<Esc>` is a sign that you didn't get that part. Your other comments on using Vim shortcuts in ST and ST shortcut in Vim are not good signs either and the part where you complain about having to adjust to your Mac's Cmd is the icing on the cake, IMO.

It may sound brutal but, from your question, it seems like you are doing too much at the same time, without organization and for, probably, no good reasons.

Switching from Windows to Mac OS X *and* switching from ST2 to Vim at the same time is sure to be confusing and I suggest you slow down a little and make a choice before you loose your mind and waste more of your time.

Which leads me to this: Why do you use a Mac and why are you using Vim?

Windows is a fine OS. Sublime is a fine editor. Even if you switch to the Mac, Sublime works very well there. So Why Vim?

If you are tired by some Sublime limitations and want the awesome power of Vim, fine. But you *must* wrap your head around its modality and awkwardness and accept to change your habit.

If you don't approach Vim with more flexibility, **you'll never get full benefits.**

If you decided to use Vim because it is trendy, I'll respectfully suggest you to stop there and go back to Sublime. Vim is weird, Vim is different, Vim is huge, Vim is a rabbit hole… if you are not ready to work with it and insist on not accepting its core design, you won't get far so why bother? You can pretty much live all your professional carreer without ever touching Vim. There's no shame in that.

Remapping `/` to `<C-f>`, on the other hand…

Comment: Some good insight. I probably could have been more productive lately if I did a little less work on meta-productivity. But at least now I am able to get work done in pretty much all environments.

Comment: But it really kind of makes me sad. I really really want to customize a terminal editor to be as usable as sublime, because there is just something incredibly elegant about a terminal based text editor. But Sublime has too many good features out of the box that are insanely difficult to all get going in vim. And it's not just about trivial stuff like `/` and `ctrl+F` (in fact i have some quibbles with Sublime's search field behavior). It's stuff like multi-select. So that's that, i guess. Wasn't meant to be.

Comment: Multi-select is a gimmick, IMO, but there are a few attempts at implementing it in Vim. As for what you think is hard to get in Vim I'm curious… Anyway, what I get is that you are focusing on superficial aspects and doing so prevents you from approaching the problem with the right state of mind. Here is my (real world, tested) advice: learn Vim one bit at a time, on the side, while still using ST2 for serious work. Don't rush out, force yourself to play by the rules. And, when you are ready, make the switch.

Comment: That definitely sounds like sound advice and I will do that. Though, for me, multi-select definitely seemed like a gimmick at first, but it is *really* expedient for renaming variables. It dramatically improves my variable-renaming diligence which leads to higher quality code. For vim to come close it needs to be able to accomplish the Cmd/Ctrl+D functionality of selecting the next instance of the selected word. Then letting me just type in its replacement. Another example of something that I have trouble configuring: pageup/pagedn functionality keeps leaving the cursor in awkward places.

Comment: A substitution or using the dot operator is just as convenient as multi-edit and it's very easy to create your own mappings and macros for even more speed and convenience. If you have more questions, you can ask them here, on superuser or on #vim. Good luck.